# A small question on notation- $\delta_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors

I'm just reading through some vector calculus notes and it begins to assume knowledge of the notation $\delta_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ in reference to tensors, but I am not familiar with this. It uses them as if they are constant and well-defined.

If someone could just explain this I would appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta

and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

these are well known usefull shorthands.

Comment: While it's unlikely that wikipedia will go down any time soon, we prefer answers on this site that are self-contained, and only use links as supplement.